# PHP - GET method with two or more parameters on the url

Tags: php, slim

I'm using `Slim framework` to create a `REST API`. I'm trying to use two parameters in the url of the method but it gives to me a `404 Page Not Found` error.

Here it's my code:

```
$app->get("/getUser/:user/:password",function($user,$password) use($app)
{
    try{
        $connection = getConnection();
        $dbh = $connection->prepare("SELECT idUser FROM users WHERE user = ? and password = ?");
        $dbh->bindParam(1,$user);
        $dbh->bindParam(2,$password);
        $dbh->execute();
        $user = $dbh->fetchObject();
        $connection = null;

        header("HTTP/1.1 200");
        header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");

        echo json_encode($user,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

If I make the method with just one parameter it works but in the same moment I put two methods it doesn't found anything.

Is it possible to send two parameters in the url? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to my problem. The problem was on the query. I translated the code to English (the parts that weren't on English before, like variables, etc) for a better comprehesion about my problem.

The problem was there, because the name of the variable `password` got a character that I think `MySQL` doesn't support and it's when I got the error. Now I changed the name of my variable to `password` and it works properly!

I put as an answer because maybe someone has the same problem as me.

Comment: Just as a note: storing passwords in plain text is [never a good idea](http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/).  You should be salting and hashing them before storage, and then comparing the hashed input to the hashed database value.

Comment: @alexw Yes, I know that. This was just some proves that I did to check how `Slimframework` worked but, to be honest, I supposed that store plaintext passwords would be a security problem in a real project because it is evident that if someone gets access to the database, all your passwords are totally exposed. I never had to work with reals project (I am still studying) until now so from two weeks ago to now I was looking for how to store a secure password (I had never searched about it) and I saw that I have to use `salt+hash` and then compare with the new hashed input as you indicate too.

Comment: @alexw I also saw that `bcrypt` could be a good option to do that. What do you think about it? **P.S:** Thanks for alert. I know that there is still a lot of people that thinks that a plaintext password it is secure. I did not know the method until few weeks ago to store it secure, but supposed that there would be a method to make them more secure. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, `bcrypt` with a salt is a good idea.  In fact, all of this is very easy in PHP 5.5+, if you use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).  `password_hash` will even salt your password automatically!

Comment: @alexw Do you mean to mix `bcrypt` with PHP functions? And just one more question: should I store the salt on the database, right?

Comment: `password_hash` actually uses `bcrypt` by default.  And, there is no need to store the salt separately.  It is already included (in its raw form) with the hashed password:

> "The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it."

Comment: @alexw Ok thank you then I will take a look to this and try to store my passwords with them. Thank you again! ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) It is possible to send 2 params in `Slim`.
2) Are you sure the value in password param is matching with any of the values in that field?

Comment: I copy it from the database directly to the url so I think it can't change. And  is it my code in the correct way? Or should I have change something?

Comment: try adding param data type like  $dbh->bindParam(1,$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: It doesn't work. I have them stored in my `MySQL` database as `varchar`, could it be the problem?

Comment: NO . You need to check your code on command prompt to see if it is compiling OK

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your last comment. Can you put an example please of what I have to do? I'm sorry, I'm totally new at PHP.